# Is there a way to programmatically check if an Azure user (or security principal) has certain required permissions?

Tags: azure, amazon-iam

I haven't been able to find any ways to check if a particular user has all the permissions they require from  a given list. I'm essentially looking for an equivalent to the simulate-principal-policy API in AWS - something that can take a userID and a list of permissions and check whether it has been granted for each entry in the list.

Have tried searching Azure docs as well as StackOverflow but haven't found any relevant answers. Most of the articles I read involve using the Azure portal and not programmatic solutions.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether I understand your question or not you need to get the user is assigned RBAC roles like (contributor, reader, etc..) using programmatically?

Comment: No I basically need to check whether a user has access to some list of permissions. Assuming this user has already previously been assigned some roles, I need to check if these roles are sufficient.

Comment: Can you share the articles that you read involving using the Azure portal and not programmatic solutions?

Comment: I didn't find an article that directly solves my issue on the portal either but I think my objective can be achieved by finding the role assignments to an user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-portal and consequently finding all permissions attached to each of these roles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-definitions-list 
What I'm looking for is a combination of these two steps and then comparing the total permissions to the required permissions given as input. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just wanted to add, I think that last comparison step is the most relevant part to finding an equivalent to AWS's simulate-principal-policy and I have not found any articles related to this functionality, either via the Azure portal or programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you can make use of below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$userObjectId = "UserObjectID"

# Specify the list of required permissions
$requiredPermissions = @("Microsoft.Authorization/*", "Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/read")
$roleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userObjectId
foreach ($roleAssignment in $roleAssignments) {
    # Get the role definition
    $roleDefinition = Get-AzRoleDefinition -Id $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionId

    # Get permissions associated with the role
    $rolePermissions = $roleDefinition.Actions

    # Check if all required permissions are present
    $missingPermissions = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $requiredPermissions -DifferenceObject $rolePermissions | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }

    if ($missingPermissions -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "User has all required permissions for role $($roleDefinition.Name)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "User is missing some permissions for role $($roleDefinition.Name)"
        Write-Host "Missing permissions:"
        $missingPermissions.InputObject
    }
}
```

[image]

If the user has multiple roles assigned, then the output will be like below:

```
$requiredPermissions = @("Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read")
```

[image]

The user has two roles assigned:

[image]

The permission **`Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read`** is for Storage Blob Data Reader not for User Access Administrator role hence the output will be like:

***Output:***

```
User has all required permissions for role Storage Blob Data Reader
User is missing some permissions for role User Access Administrator
Missing permissions:
Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/read
```

Comment: Hi, this is quite helpful. However, by programmatically, I meant using the Azure APIs to write a similar script in C++ or another language. If possible, could you share the required API calls to do this? I apologise for the confusion and once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @NaveenSharma Hi, I haven't accepted it yet as I was hoping for a modified solution post my clarification of what I meant by "programmatically." I'm new to SO hence, not sure if the norm is to accept this answer and ask a new question? I thought a comment would be a better option. If not, happy to accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @RohithPaul  If it is a new ask with the next requirement, good to raise a new Qs.